# RequireJS and window.define() conflict

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm developing a chatbox plugin (part of a live chat application), which is to be injected on my users websites. I use RequireJS for loading and running the plugin. Currently, I met a problem with one of my new user. Among libraries on its website, one of them defines "window.define" as a specific function (nothing to do with my purpose).

Problem is : on load, RequireJS defines three names in the global scope, including "define". So when I load my plugin (using RequireJS, with my main module as value of the data-main attribute), my code is actually not loaded, because of the conflict about "define".

Is there a proper way to have a control on these three names declared, to avoid such conflicts ? I know I could change code in RequireJS module to define something like "requirejsMyApp" / "defineMyAppy" and be quiet... but it's not really a proper way.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: requireJS config has a namespace option which can be used to avoid conflicts like this. Down side is it would be ```something.define``` instead of ```define```, but bound to happen when this library declare methods globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do what gillesc suggested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623790/requirejs-and-window-define-conflict#comment47391465_29623790) and use `namespace`. Here is the example build config from the [FAQ on the subject](http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#rename):

```
{
    appDir: "../",
    baseUrl: "scripts",
    dir: "../../appdirectory-build",

    paths: {
        requireLib: 'require'
    },

    //Indicates the namespace to use for require/requirejs/define.
    namespace: "foo",

    modules: [
        {
            name: "foo",
            include: ["requireLib", "main"],
            create: true
        }
    ]
}
```

The `requireLib` bit is so that RequireJS is included into the bundle. The *module* that is meant to contain RequireJS has to be named something else than `require` because the module name `require` is reserved. Once, you've done the build with the above, you just load the output of the build *rather than* loading RequireJS (because RequireJS is included in the build). Make sure to read the FAQ for caveats.

This being said, if your use-case scenario can live with the limitations of [Almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond), I'd use Almond instead. It is a loader that replaces RequireJS. It is smaller than RequireJS, and it can load code synchronously. So when you build your bundle and load it with a `script` element like this:

```
<script src="/path/to/bundle.js"></script>
```

You can be sure that by the time the browser is done processing the `script` element, the code in your bundle is available to other code that follows. If you build the bundle with RequireJS with a build configuration as shown earlier and load the bundle as above, there's no telling when the code is going to be ready to be used because RequireJS *always* loads modules asynchronously. (Yes, even if all the modules are present and RequireJS does not need to go to the network: the loading *will* be asynchronous.)